# How to get disk usage information using collectl?

Tags: monitoring, collectctl

I'm using collectl for system performance data collection. 
But I fail to find how to get disk usage information using collectl, like the total_disk_size/available_space/used_space. The tool only shows the disk activity info with "-s+D". How can I get the info showing in the output of "df -h"?

Could you pls let me know if I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: is `collectl -s+D` what you need?

Comment: No, it only shows the read/write info. I need the disk size/available/used info, just like the output of "df -h".

Comment: You may want to edit this for formatting...  Maybe shrink the text and remove the bold tags.

Comment: The editor sucks, I can't make it look good. It's the output of collectl -s+D. I removed it for no confusion.

Answer (score 2):

When I wrote collectl my focus was on performance data and not capacity planning.  My thought process was nobody would want to see disk usage every second or even every 10 seconds AND the overhead in collecting that data would be too high.  The last thing I'd want to do is run a df command every monitoring interval, especially for the cases where one has a lot of mounted devices.

Comment: Thanks for replying here - I love collectl!  As I see it, one thing that collectl is good at is having a single command and paradigm and data set that can be used to get a big-picture view of performance/usage/behavior data, which for me includes storage utilization.  And there is already the notion of disparate time intervals and data types, e.g. for "top process" data vs most of the rest.  So I'd love to see collectl somehow extended to collect hourly or daily disk storage utilization and trend data.  Or at least suggest some good synergistic tools for doing that.